# I had installed python extension (windows) but unable to see python in the right menu in integrated terminal(VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-extensions

I had installed python extension (windows) but unable to see python in the right menu in integrated terminal(VS Code). I can only see powershell unlike the tutor(Mosh Hamedani) has python.[please see the picture for better picture of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndpbx.png) Please help fixing it.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial it is unclear where you're stuck. It looks like the extension is there. You should be able to run that file in the terminal.

Comment: i was actually learning python from codewithmosh classes. so when he installed python extension he has python in the place of powershell (you can see in my previous post picture). My doubt is why am I not getting python like him?!

Comment: Based on a picture I can't help you. I linked you to a similar tutorial so you can compare and maybe re-do some of their steps.

Comment: The way your question is written you will have trouble getting a good answer. If you write a step-by-step guide describing exactly what you did (e.g. opened the windows run dialog and pasted `some/command`, then clicked the run button) you may find someone who will be able to help. As it is, it's not clear where you diverged from what you should have done.